# Is a static variable normally having the first character as uppercase?

Tags: c#

Here I have:

I have a Xamarin forms page and on the page there is a static variable:

```
namespace City
{
    public static class MS
    {
        public static int secs;
    }
}
```

What's the most common way to write this:

```
secs
```

or

```
Secs
```

Comment: I think that this boils down to opinions and as such is off-topic

Comment: Do what works for you and your team; just be consistent.

Comment: I think you have to ask the same to your Team Lead or Project manager

Comment: @Steve we can have opinions on what it should be, but there are published guidelines from the source of the framework, and also differences in how common other conventions are, and they can be addressed factually.

Comment: [Framework Design Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to **[`MSDN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d53b55ey%28v=VS.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)**, use Pascal Case for static fields.

the correct way is:

```
public static int Secs;
```

Apart from the above I would say the convention is whatever your company/team's coding standards chosen

Comment: @YvetteColomb added !

Comment: There's more variety in conventions used when the field isn't public, with `s_someName` being a common form. When it's public then breaking from what MSDN advises affects consumers as well as colleagues so it's all the more beneficial to stick with them.